# Too many initializers for char b[]

Tags: c++

It is morse code program.
I am getting error of `too many initializers for char b[]`. How can I get rid of this error?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a[72]={'A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e','F','f','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','z','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.',',','?','\'','!','/','(',')','&','@'};
    char b[]={".-",".-","-...","-...","-.-.","-.-.","-..","-..",".",".","..-.","..-.","--.","--.","....","....","..","..",".---",".---","-.-","-.-",".-..",".-..","--","--","-.","-.","---","---",".--.",".--.","--.-","--.-",".-.",".-.","...","...","-","-","..-","..-","...-","...-",".--",".--","-..-","-..-","-.--","-.--","--..","--..","-----","-----",".----",".----","..---","..---","...--","...--","....-","....-",".....",".....","-....","-....","--...","--...","---..","---..","----.","----.",".-.-.-",".-.-.-","--..--","--..--","..--..","..--..",".----.",".----.","-.-.-","-.-.--","-..-.","-..-.","-.--.","-.--.","-.--.-","-.--.-",".-...",".-..."};

    char c[40]; 
    cout<<"Enter code ";
    cin.getline(c,40);
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<72;j++){ 
            if(b[j]==c[i]){
                cout<<a[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest using an `std::map<char, std::string >` for this. It will make it a lot easier. This way you'll be able to access the morse code for any character by `charmap['a']` where `charmap` is your map of characters

Comment: `".-"` is in itself an array of chars.

Comment: As for your comment on Davids answer, if your teacher restricted you not to use strings, did you think about a possible solution not to use any strings for the morse codes representation? Have a look [here](http://www.learnmorsecode.com/) to get a hint.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<1;i++)` -- ?!

Comment: vote for my question cuz my account is blocked

Answer (score 12):

You have said that `b` is an array of `char`. But you are supplying string literals rather than individual characters. It's impossible to know what you really mean to do. Perhaps you actually want `b` to be an array of strings:

```
const char* b[] = {".-", ".-", "-...", "-...", ...};
```

Comment: const char* b[] = {".-", ".-", "-...", "-...", ...}; will this work. I have to make program of Morse code but i am restricted by my instructor not to use string.

Comment: Does your instructor hate his students?! Not using string is really harmful. Anyway, it is what it is.

Comment: @ArtizaAli _'restricted by my instructor not to use string'_ One could follow the idea of the [morse alphabet tree](http://www.learnmorsecode.com/) to solve the task without using any string literals.

Comment: he always give us challanging task

Comment: David the methode that u told me above is working but when i input a code in output the whole code

Comment: I guess you pressed the ENTER key too soon. In any case, surely the question that you asked has been answered.

Answer (score 3):

A `char` array cannot contain strings! You should initialize it with individual `char`s!

For example: `char b[] = { 'I', 'O', 'U' };`

When you desire string literals, you can use the following:

```
const char* b[] = { "II", "OO", "UU" };
```

Answer (score 2):

Either `b` should be an array of `const char*` or you should put char in the initializer list instead of string literals.

```
const char* b[]={".-",".-", ...}
```

or

```
char b[] = {'a', 'b', ...};
```

Comment: plz inbox me the syntax. that you wanna tell me

Answer (score 1):

You are not trying to store `char`s in `b`, but strings. Declare `b` as `const char *b[72] = ...` instead.

Comment: `const char *b[]`, rather. String literals may not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
static const char *a[72] =
{
    'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g',
    'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n',
    'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u',
    'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'z', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
    '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ',', '?', '\'', '!', '/', '(', ')',
    '&', '@'
};

static const char *b[] =
{
    ".-", ".-", "-...", "-...", "-.-.", "-.-.", "-..", "-..", ".", ".",
    "..-.", "..-.", "--.", "--.", "....", "....", "..", "..", ".---", ".---",
    "-.-", "-.-", ".-..", ".-..", "--", "--", "-.", "-.", "---", "---",
    ".--.", ".--.", "--.-", "--.-", ".-.", ".-.", "...", "...", "-", "-",
    "..-", "..-", "...-", "...-", ".--", ".--", "-..-", "-..-", "-.--", "-.--",
    "--..", "--..", "-----", "-----", ".----", ".----", "..---", "..---", "...--",
    "...--", "....-", "....-", ".....", ".....", "-....", "-....",
    "--...", "--...", "---..", "---..", "----.", "----.", ".-.-.-",
    ".-.-.-", "--..--", "--..--", "..--..", "..--..", ".----.", ".----.",
    "-.-.-", "-.-.--", "-..-.", "-..-.", "-.--.", "-.--.", "-.--.-", "-.--.-",
    ".-...", ".-..."
};
```

I think it will help you...